# Extract values from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a very big array with car makes and models. I've already extracted the makes into a separate array, but I am struggling to extract the models while also maintaining their association to the make.

Here is a sample of the array:

```
var dataa = new Array
        (
            ['Acura','','Integra','Mdx','Rl','Rsx','Slx','Tl','Tsx'],
            ['Aixam','','400','505','600'],
            ['Alfa romeo','','145','146','147','155','156'],
            ['Aston martin','','.','DBS','Db7','Db9']);
```

As you can see I have a multi-dimensional array with the car make (located at `dataa[0][0]`), then an empty value and then the model for this make.

I am using this code to to get the car makes:

This gives me the fist value of every nested array -> dataa[i][0]:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
  document.write(dataa[i][0] + "<br>");
}
```

My problems start HERE.

I CAN NOT extract all models and assign them to the proper car make. I have tried for-loop's, loops with brakes, while loops and loops with conditional statements but I can't do it.

Please give me some advice here. Would jQuery or some other technology help me?

Comment: The answer from @user1689607 is useful for you. If you need to associate maker and models in the same structure, then you need to create an array of objects, where every object holds 1.) the maker name, and 2.) an array of models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a loop inside your loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
    document.write("<h2>Starting new inner loop!</h2><br>");
    for (var j = 0; j < dataa[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(dataa[i][j] + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Now for every Array in the outer Array, you're doing a separate loop.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJgUD/)

Comment: I have tried this but in the second loop I changed the j not to 0 but to 2 to extract only the car models. And I don't know what code to use to associate all model with the make.

Comment: j variable shouldn't start from 0 as the first field is the car maker.

Comment: @user1729923: They are already associated in the Array. Just use index `0` directly, then start the loop at `2` as you did.

Comment: @user1729923: [Here's an updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/GJgUD/2/) I don't know exactly what output you want.

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to do is to use this array to populate two select fields and when someone select them to take the value with php and show the result from the mysql database. I know the php part, but have very little knowledge of javascript. I want to use javascript because it's faster and the information is static - only cars and models.

Comment: Yes very much like this but all car makes are in one select box and in the other select are the associated models.

Comment: @user1729923: So like this. http://jsfiddle.net/GJgUD/4/ But now I'm guessing you only want the models for the selected make to show up, right?

Comment: Yes, that is I what I need, a chained select, only the models for the selected make to show up and some good source where I can learn more about this so I don't ask stupid questions :). sometimes programming just hurts your brain :)

Comment: @user1729923: give me a minute. It's easier to disable them, but there are browser quirks when hiding them. I'll be back in a minute.

Comment: Wow I din't expect it to be so long. Thank you very much, I will use this and I will read more about on the subject. Thank you again.